# Identify periods with no immediate predecessor

Tags: sql, select

I have a calendar week list in SQL with the following structure

```
|SPECIAL_PERIOD|
201543
201601
201614
201615
201622
```

What I want to do is retrieve a list of weeks that were immediately before the special periods - but weren't special:

```
|PREVIOUS_WEEKS|
201542
201553
201613
201614 --> This one is special, so don't display
201621
```

i.e. my final list should look like:

```
|PREVIOUS_WEEKS_CLEAN|
201542
201553
201613
201621
```

Now I have two questions:

- How do I check whether a "previous_week" was special in the first place (hopefully without retrieving the initial list again and using it in a where-clause)?
- How do I manage the yearly breaks (i.e. previous week of 201601 is not 201601-1 but 201553)?

Comment: which version of sql server?

Answer (score 2):

from sql server 2012 you can use LAG() function:

```
;with
d as (
    select SPECIAL_PERIOD, dateadd(WEEK, cast(right(SPECIAL_PERIOD, 2) as int)-1, DATEFROMPARTS(cast(left(SPECIAL_PERIOD, 4) as int), 1, 1)) wk
    from MyCalendar
),
p as (
    select d.*, LAG(wk) over (order by SPECIAL_PERIOD) prev, dateadd(week, -1, wk) prev_wk
    from d
)
select *, iif(prev=prev_wk,1,0) is_special
from p 
where prev<>prev_wk -- rem this to see special weeks
order by 1
```

for sql server 2008 you can use this syntax:

```
;with
d as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by SPECIAL_PERIOD) N, SPECIAL_PERIOD, dateadd(WEEK, cast(right(SPECIAL_PERIOD, 2) as int)-1, DATEFROMPARTS(cast(left(SPECIAL_PERIOD, 4) as int), 1, 1)) wk
    from #cal
),
p as (
    SELECT d.*,p.wk prev, dateadd(week, -1, d.wk) prev_wk
    FROM D
    LEFT JOIN D p on d.N = p.n+1
)
select *, case when prev=prev_wk then 1 else 0 end is_special
from p 
where prev<>prev_wk -- rem this to see special weeks
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use the list again in a where clause, you can rename PREVIOUS_WEEKS as SPECIAL WEEKS of another copy of same list in SQL statement and do a natural join. This will give only the common entries between both. This will be conceptually same as using a WHERE clause.

I think year breaks can be managed by using numerical comparisons in the statement rather than string level comparison of the number.